# All possible "simple transformations" to align two right-handed coordinate systems?

Tags: rotations

I have two right-handed coordinate systems that are off by some unknown transformation. I know this transformation is "simple": It consists of only rotations of 0/90/180/270 degrees around the standard $x$-, $y$-, and/or $z$-axis. I want to enumerate all such "simple transformations" possible.

If there is just one rotation around one axis, then I know I have at least $4\times3=12$ such transformations, where $4$ is the number of possible rotation angles, and $3$ is the number of possible axes ($x$-, $y$-, and $z$-axes).

But apparently, we may have 2, 3, 4, ... rotations around 2, 3, 4, ... axes, up to a point where we start to have repeated transformations that can be reduced to a smaller set of rotations that produce the equivalent rotation.

How many unique "simple transformations" do we have? How do I enumerate them all?

Comment: Check out the group of symmetries of the cube: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_symmetry

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks for the pointer—I found it surprisingly useful! From what I learned there, I think the answer to my question is that we have 24 such rotation matrices (those with a determinant of $+1$)?

Comment: That’s correct.